# Tag synonym request: [minecraft-windows-10] -> [minecraft-pocket-edition]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

As of Sept. 9, Minecraft Windows 10 beta is identical to Pocket Edition. Most questions regarding either pertain to the other, with the exception of minor technicalities such as savegame location (which are already there within the PE tag).

Back when the Windows 10 version was one patch ahead of PE, I created [minecraft-windows-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-windows-10), with the full intention to synonymize later. The time for that is now.

While simply re-tagging the 3 questions with that tag to [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition) would work, I suggest a synonym, since the Windows 10 edition is, and likely will remain, branded as "Windows 10 edition", rather than PE.

Comment: Im trying to find the meta, now. But Ive seen it discussed and agreed upon that alternate editions would have a separate tag on the basis of there being (in my opinion) far less significant changes to the overall game. Minor changes include control schemes, but there is also additional content for the inclusion of VR, as well as windows 10 integration that does not appear to be fully released, yet. Either way, I think the two versions are very similar. I have often seen the compared to each other as the same. But the details need to be ironed out, before a decision is made.

Comment: The situation has changed now: Minecraft Pocket Edition, Minecraft Windows 10 Edition and so on are now officially just called "Minecraft", while the Java edition is "Minecraft Java Edition". But since "Minecraft" isn't very specific, it's usually referred to as "Pocket Edition", "Windows 10 Edition" or "Bedrock Codebase". So how should the tag be called?

Comment: Marking this feature request completed, as [minecraft-windows-10] and [minecraft-pocket-edition] are both now synonyms of [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition]

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking no. They are separate editions even though they're identical. Mojang may separate them.