# Minecraft cross-compatible edition tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merging

So, as Mojang [announced at E3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyr3XZrZssk), Minecraft is merging Pocket edition, Console edition and Windows 10 edition as one cross-compatible edition.

Currently, we have tags for each one of them. [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition) [minecraft-windows-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-windows-10) [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console) [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft)

Here's some ideas for it:

- [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) would be for any edition.
- [minecraft-pc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pc) and [minecraft-java](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java) would be for the "original java version"
- [minecraft-multiplatform](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-multiplatform) would be for the cross-compatible edition and [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition) [minecraft-windows-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-windows-10) [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console) [minecraft-cross-compatible](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-cross-compatible) would be synonyms for it.

Some similar meta posts:

- [Tag synonym request: [minecraft-windows-10] -> [minecraft-pocket-edition]](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10954/tag-synonym-request-minecraft-windows-10-minecraft-pocket-edition)
- [Tagging Minecraft for consoles](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8124/tagging-minecraft-for-consoles)

Comment: Has this merge already happened? If not: then this post is too early, merging the stuff now would just cause issues for everyone who plays any of the currently different games.

Comment: The server stuff has been merged for a while now, but the names aren't.

Comment: The Tag "Minecraft" for everything is a good idea - I feel that Minecraft-java would be better because Minecraft-PC is somewhat Windows specific but Mac OS, Linux also uses the JAVA edition.

Comment: The main reason for the differences in names is because all the different versions have diferent features that make them unique. One tag as "Minecraft" would lead to major confusion on a question about something unique to a specific version. Until the so called "Better Together" update (I did some reading on it), which combines ALL versions, seperate tags should be kept.

Comment: We should figure out what we're going to do sooner rather than later so that when the update drops, we can quickly, easily, and efficiently make those changes.  Which isn't to say that I 100% agree with the proposal you've laid out here.  IMHO, [tag:minecraft] should remain the tag for the original java version, for instance.

Comment: As the beta of this update has come out (https://minecraft.net/en-us/article/beta-test-better-together), we should figure what are we going to do.

Comment: The PC Edition of Minecraft is now officially called "Minecraft Java Edition"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft Bedrock Edition](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12856/minecraft-bedrock-edition)

Comment: @FabianRöling Actually it is duplicate of this.

Answer (score 2):

After learning more about the different versions, I no longer agree with this listing. A new discussion is here: [Pocket Edition is now Bedrock. Why PE is not a synonym? When should the PE tag be used?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14800/171580)

### Old answer

(Posting as answer, because it's long, has formatting and at least offers a partial solution.)

I would say we should allow as much specification as possible without getting name collisions. This is a complicated topic and there are a lot of things the same between all versions, but also a lot of things different between them, so I would say: The more tags, the better. Otherwise people would have to specify this in every question anyway.

- [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) for everything: Java, together, PlayStation, raspberry, education, …
- [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition) for questions specifically about Android, iPhone, iPad, Windows Phone, etc. ports of Minecraft (can be important, because e.g. some graphics settings differ)
- [minecraft-windows-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-windows-10) for questions specifically about Minecraft on the desktop port of Bedrock Edition (or maybe including Windows Phone?)
- [minecraft-legacy-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-legacy-console) for the legacy port on PlayStation
- [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console) for the consoles that can play with the others (the ones developed by 4J Studios)
- [minecraft-bedrock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock) for the Windows 10 and mobile versions, the ones that actually share most of their code, with tag synonyms [minecraft-multiplatform](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-multiplatform), [minecraft-together](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-together), [minecraft-unified](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-unified) and [minecraft-cross-compatible](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-cross-compatible)
- [minecraft-education](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-education) for the education edition
- [minecraft-raspberry-pi](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-raspberry-pi) for the discontinued Raspberry Pi edition
- [minecraft-java](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java) for Minecraft Java edition
- And then also one tag per device, like Wii U, PS4, iPad, even Linux and Mac for the Java edition, because there can for example be launcher issues specific to one operating system. This could act like the "environment" field on the bugtracker.

One more question: What to do with the questions that already have these tags? For example some of those that have the tag [minecraft-console-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console-edition) now are e.g. on the Wii U, which will be the "together" edition, but some are about PlayStation that won't get that update.

Comment: That sounds fine for me.

Comment: I edited it a bit, please look at the diff. And what about the questions that already have these tags? Any idea? Should someone go through them manually? Should we accept that some old questions have the wrong tag? Is there some clever way to automatically update them?

Comment: The "minecraft" tag has always been used to point at the java version, changing this suddenly is going to cause confusion.

Comment: Mojang changed it. It's the new official name, while only "Minecraft" is supposed to refer to Bedrock Edition.

Comment: Another year of inactivity. Should my suggestion now be implemented? This constantly wrong tagging is driving me mad more and more, so I'll go on a retagging spree soon anyway. Might as well use a finalised and agreed upon ruleset for that rather than changing everything now based on the old rules and then changing it all again later.

Answer (score -5):

Maybe "Minecraft-BTU" or "MC-BTU" for MC BTU?

Comment: P.S. BTU is Better Together Update.