# Why do we have so many Minecraft tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, minecraft, sub-tags

Most games have a single tag, and all questions about that game fall under that one tag.  Some games have extra tags for various DLCs.  But minecraft has too many to count.  Literally, too many to count - the [tag search](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags) won't list them all.

We even have a minecraft tag for meta, but I don't see any other games with their own tag in meta.

[image]

Are all of these tags necessary? Or did we get carried away?

Comment: Looks like a lot of these are for mod packs within Minecraft. We wouldn't want to remove "minecraft" from those tags as it would make them less obvious, but tags for specific mod packs make sense also since they generally alter the core experience. So for mod-pack-specific Minecraft tags I don't see any issue.

Comment: Another aspect of this is the increase in the number of versions lately; [minecraft-console], [minecraft-pocket-edition], and [minecraft-windows-10] might technically be the same as [minecraft-bedrock-edition] now, but then again this hasn't always been the case which makes that part of it slightly messy

Comment: Related: [Minecraft Bedrock Edition](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12856/4797)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 3 types of tags beyond the base Minecraft tag here:

1. Core parts of minecraft: things like Redstone, Commands, Resource pack. These are usually quite complicated and a game in themselves to get to work. Having tags for them allows for users to specialize in specific tags. A user might want to focus on command block tags, but doesn't want to see technical support questions.
2. Different versions of the base game: console edition, Bedrock edition, server, Realms,... Each version of the game is slightly different with regards to features and ways to handle problems. Having tags for them allows the asker to clearly define what he can and cannot do.
3. 3rd party software and expansions for Minecraft: Feed the Beast, Bukkit, Forge,... These usually change the base experience of Minecraft significantly and as such usually have way different questions compared to the base game. Having tags for them allows for a combination of specialization of answerers and scope definition for askers.

There isn't really a problem here. Each of these tags has their own niche, and merging or removing tags will only serve to either make questions less clear or make the tags themselves vague.

Comment: Well, there is still the problem that some Minecraft tags aren't clearly defined and some names don't match the official names given by Mojang. [This question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12523/minecraft-cross-compatible-edition-tags/12650#12650) is about that, but was mainly ignored for the last year.