# Pocket Edition is now Bedrock. Why PE is not a synonym? When should the PE tag be used?

Tags: discussion, tags, minecraft

[From Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Bedrock_Edition):

> Bedrock Edition (also known as the Bedrock Version or just Bedrock) refers to the multi-platform family of editions of Minecraft developed by Mojang AB, Xbox Game Studios, 4J Studios, and SkyBox Labs. Prior to this term, as the engine originated with Pocket Edition, this entire product family **was** referred to as "Pocket Edition", "MCPE", or "Pocket/Windows 10 Edition".

This makes me think that [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition) is a synonym of [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition), but is not. The excerpt of [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition) says:

> Only use this tag if the question specifically pertains to the Pocket Edition version of Minecraft - that is, features or functionality that are unique to the Android & iOS versions of Minecraft.

I feel that the tag should not exist, because the PE Branding is no longer used and the Android and iOS version of the game have the same features and functionality as the other Bedrock releases (with the difference being platform limitations).

[image]

In this case, I would use [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) in combination with [android](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) or [ios](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) for problems or specific features on those platforms.

- Why [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition) is not a synonym of [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition)?
- When [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition) should be used instead of [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition)?

Comment: Argghghg this is a thing the mods were discussing but we never actually got around to actioning. :( :( :( See [this rename request](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12856/28182)

Comment: If it was a problem then with PE, W10 and Bedrock, is now a bigger problem after the deprecation of all Console Editions with the release of Bedrock for PS4.

Comment: No, that isn't a problem with the tagging system; [tag:minecraft-console] can continue to exist for the discontinued Legacy Console Edition.

Comment: The tags itself are not a problem, but in combination with the excerpts they can confuse some users.

Comment: Perhaps editing the excerpts to indicate the game is now discontinued would help there, but tags for games that are no longer played must be preserved. After all, the questions are still on the site.

Comment: The problem here is that PE is the old branding for BE, so there are two tags for the same game. And there is also the problem that CE might be used instead of BE, so something like [minecraft-legacy-console] might be better.

Comment: @Mast I [did that](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/282036) for console edition already. Pocket Edition wasn't discontinued, it was renamed "Bedrock Edition" and expanded to more platforms.

Comment: There's also the problem that people often use the Minecraft Java tag and talk about a console. Then I have no clue which version of Minecraft they are actually playing. Should I just guess in those cases or vote to close as unclear?

Comment: Congrats on the fifth post on this topic in 6 years. :D Hopefully this time something actually happens with it. Can we please all agree to agree on something in the first half of 2020 and then actually do it this time? If I understand it right, the Minecraft related tags on gamingSE are at least 6 years behind the actual reality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This had been discussed before [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12523/171580), but without a conclusion (or really any wider response at all). I had written an answer there, but in the >2 years since then I learned more about the different versions, so I want to now suggest a different structure:

- No tag called [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) at all. It would either mean all the different versions, which would be about as vague as a [mario](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mario) tag, or the MCPE version, because Microsoft rebranded it to only be called "Minecraft" (a decision that I heavily disagree with). Either way, people would end up just tagging anything Minecraft related with that tag, either because they don't care to read or because the tag situation is confusing. By not having a tag called [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft), people are forced to choose an actually fitting tag from the ones below, which saves me a lot of re-tagging effort and asking back which game they are actually talking about.
- [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) for the original, written in Java.
- [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) with the synonyms [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition), [minecraft-windows-10-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-windows-10-edition), [minecraft-better-together](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-better-together) and whatever else seems fitting: The version for phones, consoles and Windows 10, written in C++.
- [minecraft-legacy-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-legacy-console) for the no longer supported version that used to run on consoles, developed by a different game studio.
- No tag [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console) at all, it only causes confusion between [minecraft-legacy-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-legacy-console) and [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition). Same reasons as for [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft). There are still posts that were asked recently of which I have no idea which of the two they are about. And some people even use it for commands questions, because they "open a console".
- I do not know whether "Education edition" is really a separate game or just a collective term for a number of features of Bedrock edition. If it is a separate game, the tag [minecraft-education-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-education-edition) should definitely exist, if not, maybe a similarly named tag should exist anyway, maybe not. Someone else should answer this.
- [minecraft-raspberry-pi](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-raspberry-pi) for the discontinued and very basic version for the Raspberry Pi.
- [minecraft-4k](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-4k) for "Minecraft 4K", a less than 4 Kilobyte big version of Minecraft made by Notch in a programming contest. Yes, people actually play that and might have questions about it.
- [minecraft-classic-browser](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-classic-browser) for https://classic.minecraft.net, a version of Minecraft Classic that can be played in a browser.
- [minecraft-story-mode](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-story-mode) for the vaguely Minecraft related story game by a different game studio.
- [minecraft-dungeons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-dungeons) for the game called "Minecraft dungeons" which I don't really know anything about, except that it is not Minecraft, but it is made by Mojang.
- [minecraft-earth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-earth) for the vaguely Minecraft related mixed reality game for phones, similar to Pokémon Go.

Unlike my old answer, I do not think that a tag per device specifically for Minecraft should exist. Tags for devices already exist and can be used together with the tag for the game.

---

Now the hard part: Migration. This is my suggestion what should be done with the currently existing tags:

- [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) can just be renamed to [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition).
- [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands) can stay as it is. It will have the problem that most of MCBE commands questions will be duplicates of "how to do thing X with NBT in MCBE", but those can just be closed. A lot of commands are still very different, because MCBE still doesn't have the commands of MCJava 1.13+, but hopefully that will be fixed relatively soon. Important: Whenever a question uses [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands) without also using one of the edition tags and without any indication which game it is, it should be closed as "needs details" in my opinion. This is **not** being done currently.
- [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition) should become a synonym of [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition). Hopefully that already does all the necessary migration for this tag automatically. I don't know what happens when a tag with questions in it is turned into a synonym of another tag or if that is even possible, hopefully it just works.
- [minecraft-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-server): Luckily dedicated servers on MCBE are pretty new, so it should be fine to just rename it to [minecraft-java-edition-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition-server) and check which questions in it are additionally also tagged with [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition) or [xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox) or anything else that indicates that it is not MCJava. Those should get the newly to create tag [minecraft-bedrock-edition-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition-server).
- [minecraft-redstone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-redstone) could stay as it is. Pretty much every weird edge case is different between MCJava and MCBE, but the most common applications of redstone should be very similar, so I think it should be enough to have one tag shared between the games. The same logic of closing questions that don't specify an edition applies here as for [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands).
- [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console): This is the most difficult one. It should definitely be renamed to [minecraft-legacy-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-legacy-console), but that will probably mislabel about half of all questions that used the tag recently. The big problem is that it is very difficult to differentiate which ones are for which edition. If someone volunteers to clean this up after the rename, I would be happy about it.
- [minecraft-feed-the-beast](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-feed-the-beast) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mods) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-bukkit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bukkit) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) can stay as it is, it is already correct.
- [minecraft-windows-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-windows-10) should be renamed to [minecraft-windows-10-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-windows-10-edition) and become a synonym of [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition).
- [minecraft-forge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-forge) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-tekkit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-tekkit) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-realms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-realms) should be renamed to [minecraft-java-edition-realms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition-realms) and then searched through for MCBE Realms questions, which should get a newly to create tag [minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms). If noone else volunteers to do this, I could do it, since it's only 61 questions and I can probably differentiate MCJava Realms from other games.
- [minecraft-spigot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-spigot) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-buildcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-buildcraft) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-industrialcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-industrialcraft) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-thaumcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-thaumcraft) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-technic-pack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-technic-pack) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava. (But maybe its description should be changed, it sounds pretty braggy.)
- [minecraft-resource-packs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-resource-packs) can stay as it is, as far as I know resource packs do not exist for MCBE. (Also, I should change its description.)
- [minecraft-worldedit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-worldedit) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-forestry](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-forestry) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-direwolf20](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-direwolf20) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-mcedit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mcedit) should be renamed to [mcedit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mcedit), since that is its official name. I think this external program works for multiple editions, but I would assume that it's fairly similar for all of them and even comes bundled as one executable, so multiple tags for the MCJava, MCBE etc. version are not needed, instead tags like [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) should be used together with [mcedit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mcedit).
- [minecraft-computercraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-computercraft) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-tinkers-construct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-tinkers-construct) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-story-mode](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-story-mode) can stay as it is, it is already correct.
- [minecraft-hexxit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-hexxit) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-pixelmon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pixelmon) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-applied-energistics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-applied-energistics) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-optifine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-optifine) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-datapack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-datapack) can stay as it is, this feature only exists in MCJava.
- [minecraft-comes-alive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-comes-alive) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-education-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-education-edition) depends on whether it is actually a separate game, as mentioned above.
- [minecraft-redpower](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-redpower) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-mystcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mystcraft) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-redpower](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-redpower) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [mc-equivalent-exchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mc-equivalent-exchange) should be renamed to [minecraft-equivalent-exchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-equivalent-exchange).
- [minecraft-railcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-railcraft) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-launcher](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-launcher) can stay as it is, if the "launcher" concept is unique to MCJava. Otherwise this should be discussed separately.
- [minecraft-mcpatcher](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mcpatcher) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-aether](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-aether) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-factorization](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-factorization) looks like a MCJava mod. If that is true, it can stay as it is.
- [minecraft-towny](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-towny) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-classic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-classic) should be renamed to [minecraft-classic-browser](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-classic-browser). Only one of the four questions in that tag might potentially be about the actual old version of Minecraft, but that one is very unclear anyway and I just voted to close it as such. I will also write a tag description for it.
- [minecraft-millenaire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-millenaire) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-earth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-earth) can stay as it is, it is already correct.
- [minecraft-pi-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pi-edition) should be renamed to [minecraft-raspberry-pi-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-raspberry-pi-edition)
- [minecraft-mekanism](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mekanism) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-crash-landing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-crash-landing) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-oceancraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-oceancraft) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-te](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-te) should be renamed to [minecraft-thermal-expansion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-thermal-expansion) and the description changed accordingly.
- [minecraft-voltz](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-voltz) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-bigdig](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bigdig) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-extra-utilities](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-extra-utilities) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-enderio](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-enderio) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-skyfactory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-skyfactory) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-twilight-forest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-twilight-forest) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-portal-gun](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-portal-gun) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-westeroscraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-westeroscraft) can stay as it is, it is an MCJava map+server.
- [minecraft-useful-pets](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-useful-pets) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.
- [minecraft-pocket-mine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-mine) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCBE.
- [minecraft-seus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-seus) should be renamed to [minecraft-shader](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-shader) to allow for more diverse shader questions in it. Currently there is only one question and no watchers, so it should be fine if the tag scope is broadened.
- [minecraft-biomes-o-plenty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-biomes-o-plenty) can stay as it is, it is automatically for MCJava.

[minecraft-4k](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-4k) and [minecraft-dungeons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-dungeons) should be created as soon as a question is asked about those games.

Some synonyms should also be changed in this migration:

- [minecraft-beta](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-beta) should be removed. It was never used and the "beta" development stage is not unique to MCJava.
- [minecraft-smp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-smp) should be removed. It was never used and servers are not unique to MCJava.
- [minecraft-nether](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-nether) should be removed. It was used a few times, but the Nether is not unique to MCJava and people can probably figure out which tag to use instead.
- [smp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smp) should be removed. It was used a few times, but just redirecting to one of the two server tags is not a good idea.

---

Any feedback? Should we do it like this? Did anyone even read this entire 12674 character post? :D
If yes, when should it be done? I would volunteer to do most of this, but I have never renamed or deleted a tag, so some people should definitely verify that everything is going right before the rest is done.

Edit: I am currently researching how to do tag renamings, mergings, burninations, etc. and the etiquette around those. I will create a new gaming meta post suggesting these changes once I am done and have made a concrete plan how to proceed.

Edit 2: Research is done, the new post is [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14846/171580).

Comment: "Did anyone even read this entire 13181 character post?" yes I did, and it was beautiful seeing that someone took the time to take a look at all of the Minecraft tags that are on Gaming.SE

Comment: Why don't you just delete all the single-question mod tags? (retagging the question to [tag:minecraft-mods])

Comment: Oww, my head :(

Comment: @pppery Because a bunch of people might only follow the tag for one mod, are experts for that one mod and not be interested in other mods. And I think this is likely the case, because from the little I saw of the question lists in those tags, it appears almost as if a higher percentage of questions is answered that uses those tags than in general Minecraft.

Comment: While I agree that might be the case, I agree with @pppery that having a single-question tag for a mod isn't worth it. Cleaning up the tags to be a more concise list will help people find what they're looking for faster. It shouldn't be a big deal to someone to follow a "mods" tag, and only care about/search for the one particular mod they know, and if it was that popular there would be more than one question about it. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Alright, so should every mod-specific tag with two or less questions be deleted?

Comment: I think instead of doing it off of only the amount of questions we should also delete tags that haven't been used in a while. Maybe 6+ months would be a good time frame.

Comment: So if(question count < 3 && latest question older than 6 months), then delete tag?

Comment: I've started cleaning up [tag:minecraft-console]. You're right, the tag is misused on a lot of questions

Comment: So you're currently separating it between [tag:minecraft-console], [tag:minecraft-commands] and either [tag:minecraft-bedrock] or [tag:minecraft-pocket-edition]? That should not conflict with the renaming and re-structuring then.

Comment: What I've been doing is primarily retagging questions to [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition], with occasional other cleanup when I see a question that needs it. That should be compatible with any latter tag merges.