# Inconsistency in Minecraft related tags

Tags: discussion, tags, minecraft, retag-request

We have a tag called [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands). You must use it with another minecraft tag to specify. Same goes for redstone.

We have [minecraft-java-edition-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition-server) and [minecraft-bedrock-edition-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition-server). These currently have an argument for whether they should be used alone or not (I believe they should NOT be used alone). Same goes for realms.

I'm guessing this is just how it happened but in my mind they should be consistent. I at least think we should just pick a choice and stick with it. Either we join [minecraft-java-edition-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition-server) and [minecraft-bedrock-edition-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition-server) into [minecraft-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-server) or we split [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands) into two tags, one per edition. If you didn't know [minecraft-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-server) *used* to be a thing, but it got wiped in the java/bedrock split.

**Can we be consistent? If so, which situation would we be leaning?** I see two main points on each side:

- If we join the server tags, [this argument is killed.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15692/258509) We wouldn't need to even fight this if we opt for the [minecraft-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-server) route.
- If we opt to split [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands), there will be no more messing around with the people that just tag their questions [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands). It gets annoying that some people ignore comments asking for version/edition, but seem to respond to everything else. These make me and I bet others hate this tag for this reason. It's good except this happens way too much.

So, which of these two tag actions shall we take, if any?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 idc, i just changed it because your edit made it say two different things in different places; the last thing i want is the post asking for consistency to be inconsistent in its  requests

Answer (score 4):

*Please wait 5–15 seconds for the images on this post to load. I'm afraid I can't upload them to SE Imgur because the files are `.svg`.*

---

I feel like I am in an appropriate position to answer this question based on my previous experiences, including one very similar to the issue that is going on now.

For those of you who haven't read [my profile page](/users/250180/expertcoder14?tab=profile) yet, I am an administrator on the [Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes Wiki](https://ktane.fandom.com/wiki/User:ExpertCoder14) on Fandom. I have dealt with a similar issue on my wiki before involving categories, which act like tags on our wiki.

There are two ways to classify modules in KTaNE: whether they are from the vanilla game or modded, and whether they're regular or needy. At first, I made the following categories:

[image: Old KTaNE Wiki Categories]

That looks fine and dandy, but I noticed a flaw with this setup. There is, in reality, no need for this extra segregation between different categories. A setup that combines categories like this would actually be better:

[image: New Categories]

With this second setup, it is actually better than the older setup because of overlapping categories. This allows us to search questions better, because it allows us to narrow down our search by specifying more than one category. *It's like the difference between Gmail and normal email.* Mail only allows one folder for each item. Gmail allows multiple. **We allow multiple tags on our posts. Let's take advantage of that.**

For example, to get a search of all modded needy modules, you would use a search like: `[mod-modules] [needy-modules]` to get a list. This should be the same on Arqade, where *the more you specify in the search*, the *narrower your results get*. This is not the case in the first example, where specifying just one tag would get results too narrow.

Say you wanted any regular modules, no matter the origin. With the first example, you would need to do `[regular-modules] or [mod-modules]` which does not make sense from a searching perspective. **We're a knowledge base, not a forum, just like my wiki. Therefore, our site and its tags should be optimized from a searching perspective, not an asking and answering perspective.** Search engines give you stuff on topics similar to your actual destination, unless you explicitly ask to exclude them.

Now we're back to the original problem with our server tags. Right now we have one of these two, depending on what you think of [this argument](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15692/258509):

[image: Old Arqade Categories] or [image: test]

When we should have:

[image: New Arqade Categories]

With this improved setup, if you search `[minecraft-servers]`, you'll get questions on all types of servers, Java, and Bedrock. Only want the Java servers? Add `[minecraft-java-edition]` to your search. Want Java gameplay questions that are not about servers? Simply use the inversion: `[minecraft-java-edition] -[minecraft-servers]`. **We have a search function that will let us specify the exact combination of tags that we want. Let's take advantage of it.**

So I'm sorry to [Fabian Röling](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/171580) for undoing one of [your proposed changes](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14812/250180), but I think that this would greatly benefit us to change the tags so that the search can run the way it's supposed to.

---

I understand that some users may be angry because that increases the potential for a user specifying [minecraft-servers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-servers) without specifying their edition, like with [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands). To combat this problem, I have made [this feature-request](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15699/250180).

Comment: Yes this is also what I'd prefer, especially since the tag names become so long!