# Ability to block/warn about certain combinations of tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-warning-request

We already have [blocked tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295148/805262) and tag warnings, but we need to expand this feature to block or warn about certain *combinations* of tags, not just the presence/absence of a certain tag.

This argument stems off of the problem where multiple tags are necessary, like with [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands). We could have something like:

[image: Minecraft Servers Tag Block]

This example was from [this argument](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15698/250180).

Here, the tag would be blocked *until* you add one of the other tags that are required with it. We could have a combination block on [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands) unless the question also has [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) or [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition). This will catch people making the common mistake before it happens, saving them from having to wait long periods of time as their question is closed and reopened.

We could do this also with combination tag warnings:

[image: If your question pertains to both editions of Minecraft, we'd prefer if you used a seperate question for each edition, unless you're sure the answer would be exactly the same in both editions.]

If implemented, this should be used sparingly, only for commonly mistaken tags. It should not be used for obviously wrong things that no one would actually do (like blocking the combination [keep-talking-and-nobody-explodes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keep-talking-and-nobody-explodes) [papers-please](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papers-please))

Comment: I don't believe this is *presently* possible, but I like it

Comment: I found [an identical feature request dating back to 2015 on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306640/can-we-have-tag-warnings-or-full-blocks-for-particular-tag-combinations)

Answer (score 1):

I agree, the functionality to block or warn based on tags would be useful, but my understanding is that this functionality already exists.

According to [this post on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360751/179041):

> ...there is a special field in the site settings where one needs to add a regex for the title, body or tags and specify the text that will be shown when the regex returns true.

It should be possible using Regex pattern matching to detect the scenarios above, and block/warn based on that.

I agree with your last point, stuff like this should be used sparingly. Do you think it's worth raising your scenarios above as [tag-warning-request](/questions/tagged/tag-warning-request)s? Do we often get questions that only use the [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands) tag? Or that use **both** the Java and Bedrock edition tags?

If so, assuming community support - we should be able to add [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) to those requests, and the SE developers will be able to review and potentially add it for us.

Comment: Are you sure you answered regarding the main point of the question? The main point was not about the existence of tag warnings themselves, but instead to make them triggerable by *combinations* of tags in general. However, the way our site is right now, it does not warrant any of these, but I do think that a feature to block/warn about *combinations* of tags is a feature that other places may appreciate.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 - I have re-organised my answer a bit better to directly address your question.