# Tagging for Minecraft Bedrock Edition

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request, minecraft

Prior art: [Minecraft cross-compatible edition tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12523/minecraft-cross-compatible-edition-tags), [Tag synonym request: [minecraft-windows-10] -> [minecraft-pocket-edition]](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10954/tag-synonym-request-minecraft-windows-10-minecraft-pocket-edition), [Tagging Minecraft for consoles](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8124/tagging-minecraft-for-consoles)

As part of the official release of the Better Together Update in September 2017, Minecraft combined [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition), [minecraft-windows-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-windows-10), and [minecraft-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox), all into a single version called the Bedrock Edition. Soon, this will also include the Nintendo Switch version (which curiously doesn't have a synonym).

These games all share the same code, and have cross-platform multiplayer. **They are all considered the same edition of the game, as far as Mojang is concerned.**

I'd like to propose that we:

- create a [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) tag, with the previous tags [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition), [minecraft-windows-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-windows-10) as synonyms.
- change the synonym [minecraft-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox) to point to [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition).
- create a synonym from [minecraft-switch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-switch) to [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition), *once it releases*
- create a synonym from [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) to [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft), since that's the new official name for the PC version.
- do something about [minecraft-ps3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-ps3), since it is distinct and not part of the Bedrock Edition.

I'd especially like some discussion on that last point, but here's what I have in mind. If:

1. a question is tagged [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft), [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console), or both; **and**
2. the question either is tagged [ps3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps3) or contains "PS3" in the body text

then we retag it as [minecraft-ps3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-ps3). Otherwise, we retag it as [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition).

Comment: Sounds like a great idea. I was going to suggest it myself.

Comment: While this is a good idea, I'm a little worried about the "Do something about [minecraft-ps3]" as that is a bit of an unknown. How should this be handled? Do we need to go and retag questions? Do we just remove the synonym and any new questions about the ps3 version can use the separated tag?

Comment: @Robotnik Agreed. That's the reason for the [tag:discussion] tag, actually: I'm not sure what we should do about it. (I probably should've highlighted this in the post.) IMO these never should have been merged in the first place. I'll add my thoughts to the post.

Comment: Aside: I'm surprised that Meta posts can be tweeted! Is that really the correct behaviour?

Comment: This is strange: ATM I don't see minecraft-ps3/xbox/switch tags... I wonder why

Comment: @alex2003super [tag:minecraft-switch] doesn't exist. [tag:minecraft-ps3] and [tag:minecraft-xbox] are [tag synonyms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) for [tag:minecraft-console].

Comment: @Schism Oh, this makes sense. I was on mobile and for some reason they weren't showing up in tags as synonyms. Dunno if bug, expected behaviour or /r/crappydesign

Comment: Since only Next-gen systems (excluding ps4) have the Bedrock update, why not have "minecraft" for pc, "minecraft-bedrock" for those that have bedrock, "minecraft-oldgen" for Xbox 360 and ps3 (since they are essentially the same game, with a few differences in the controls, which could then be specified in the question and/or answer), and minecraft-ps4 for the ps4?

Comment: Oh wow, this question comes up a lot, but it seems to never lead anywhere. I hope this time something will actually happen: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14800

Comment: Given that this discussion was superseded by [The great Minecraft tag family cleanup!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14846/28182), and that the majority of tag renames/synonyms in this post have been applied, I'm going to mark this as [status-completed], and a duplicate (so that future readers are directed to the more 'up to date' status of Minecraft tags). If there's further discussion to be had, please continue it on the aforementioned newer post, or raise a new one :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### How Minecraft versions are organized

There are three main Minecraft codebases. To simplify, I'm gonna call them *Java, Bedrock* and *Console*.

Following are the versions of **Java codebase**:

- **Classic, Indev, Infdev, Alpha, Beta:** pre-release development versions of the PC game
- **Minecraft** (please note that, while this term is officially to be considered outdated, for most gamers this is what "Minecraft" means): the first, original Minecraft edition, that is playable on literally any OS that can handle Java and OpenGL. In fact, it is available for Windows, macOS, *nix systems (Unix, Linux etc.). Quite interestingly, it can even be run on Android, up to version 6 (Marshmallow), with a tool called *Boardwalk*. It has not cross-platform capabilities, however, being multiplayer based on a decentralized server infrastructure, online play is 100% platform agnostic, as long as everyone is playing this edition of the game. Being coded in Java, this version is highly reverse-engineerable so mods for it can be easily developed.

It has now been renamed to:

- **Minecraft: Java Edition**: another name for the original version of Minecraft. Just that. This change is relatively recent.
- **Minecraft Server**: a minimal, command line implementation of the Java codebase, in the form of a JAR executable. It does not require a license to run and can be used to create a multiplayer server, even if for bigger servers the use of a custom version (like Spigot) is recommended.

Following are the versions of **Bedrock codebase**:

- **Minecraft: Pocket Edition (a.k.a. PE)**: a mobile edition of the game, completely different from both the console and Java codebases, originally only developed as a secondary, smaller game, to be played on the go. It was made available on iOS, Android (both through the Google Play and Amazon App stores) and Windows Phone, even if - ironically - the latter version was deprecated pretty soon. The game is written in C++.

It has now been officially renamed into:

- **Minecraft**: although the name change was quite controversial, it has been officially applied. This name now represents PE, Windows 10 Edition and was also ported to Xbox and Nintendo Switch: this version completely replaced the *Xbox One* and *Nintendo Switch* editions of the game. It provides cross-platform play across different consoles and devices via Xbox Live, although only on Xbox consoles is a subscription required for online play. Microsoft approved servers are also accessible from all platforms, but only from "non-jailed" platforms (Windows, Android, iOS) can user-created servers be connected to. The only official way to "create" a server on this platform is to purchase a *Minecraft Realms* subscription, which gives you an online world hosted by Microsoft in the cloud. The game also features a store, where user-created content can be sold and purchased, using an in-game currency called "Minecraft Coins". It should be noted that the only way to obtain those is by purchasing them with real money. Third-party server software exists, though it is often incompatible with updates and lacks core features, such as mobs. This version supports a very basic native modding API in the form of "Behaviour Packs".
- **Windows 10 Edition** (now merged into Minecraft): it is a UWP version of the game, downloadable from Microsoft Store on any *x86* device running Windows 10 (only 10, no 8.1/8/7/older OS is supported). It mustn't be confused with *Minecraft: Java Edition*, which can also run on Windows 10, but on many other platforms too.
- **Raspberry Pi Edition**: a now abandoned application, based on old Minecraft PE and developed specifically for the ARM-based Raspberry Pi Single Board Computer. It comes included with the free Raspbian operating system, which is a distribution of Linux for the Raspberry Pi. It is completely free and it includes a Python language interpreter, which allows users to make the Minecraft world interact with sensors, GPIO pins, cameras et cetera.
- **Apple TV Edition**: basically Pocket Edition without multiplayer for Apple TV (5th+ gen). It isn't getting any recent updates past 1.1.x: a "dead" game, as it was not even merged into the unified Minecraft game. Officially it is still an active Minecraft edition.
- **New 3DS Edition**: this edition for the Nintendo New 3DS is relatively new, albeit based on an old *Minecraft Pocket Edition* release, with additional features such as multiplayer with other N3DS consoles and touch screen support. It's unclear wether or not it will be further developed in the future.
- **Gear VR Edition**: this is an exclusive edition to Samsung Oculus Gear VR virtual reality platform. It gets the same updates as the unified *Minecraft* and has full cross-platform multiplayer capabilities with other Minecraft unified versions. It is controlled with a gamepad and the user can switch between an immersive, first person mode, and a mode where they are in a virtual room playing in front of a giant screen (the latter to reduce VR motion sickness).

The **Console** codebase was developed by 4J Studios, not Mojang. After Microsoft's acquisition of Mojang, the Redmond company has been constantly attempting to unify this platform with *Bedrock*. Following are the versions of **Console codebase**:

- **Minecraft: Xbox 360 Edition**: this is the first *Console* edition to ever be developed. It is exclusive to the Xbox 360 console and gets still updated today. *Console* editions are pretty limited compared to the others, but eventually they catch up with most of the features implemented in *Bedrock* and *Java*. This edition is for a *last gen* console, so it has a low world size and short draw distance. It can export worlds to be imported into *Xbox One Edition* and it features some exclusive Xbox DLC, as well as the standard content available on other *Console* platforms.
- **Minecraft: Xbox One Edition**: this version is officially deprecated and a free upgrade to *Minecraft* (the Bedrock one) is offered to its users. Online play was shut down and it is instead available on the *Bedrock*-based game. It has the same DLC as Xbox 360. This edition is for a *current gen* console, so it has a high world size and long draw distance. Additionally, this edition can import worlds from Xbox 360, but not export them back, however they can be exported to the new *Minecraft* game.
- **Minecraft: PS3 Edition**: this game is almost identical to the *Xbox 360 Edition*, exception made for a *PS Vita* world import/export feature and exclusive *PlayStation* DLCs.
- **Minecraft: PS Vita Edition**: an edition made specifically for the PS Vita handheld console. Based on the *PS3 Edition*, it implements basic support for its touch screen and local *ad-hoc* multiplayer. It has a shorter render distance compared to the PS3.
- **Minecraft: PS4 Edition**: it is almost identical to the *Xbox One Edition*, exception made for the touchpad support, exclusive PlayStation DLC and PS3/PS Vita world import features (worlds cannot be exported back though). Due to Sony's refusal to replace this version with *Bedrock*, this version is currently active, online play included.
- **Minecraft: Wii U Edition**: as the name suggests, it is a version for the Wii U console. It is similar to the PS3/Xbox edition, but it runs at a lower resolution and is more expensive; the higher price is justified by some included exclusive Nintendo DLC. It is still getting updates.
- **Minecraft: Nintendo Switch Edition**: this version is officially abandoned, players are offered a free copy of the new unified *Minecraft*, while on this edition the online servers are shut down. Worlds created on this version can be converted to the format for the new game on Nintendo Switch. World size is similar to that of next-gen consoles.

**Edit:**

### This is my idea for tags:

- [minecraft-redstone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-redstone), [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands) and all modded Minecraft tags should be left as they are IMHO.
- [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) should be created, with [minecraft-macos](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-macos) [minecraft-mac](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mac) and [minecraft-linux](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-linux) as synonyms, being Java Edition the only one available on these platforms.
- [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) should be a synonym of either [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) or [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition), depending on whether we want to make it easier to understand for either newer players or "veterans", I'd guess. These days *"Minecraft" doesn't mean much.*
- [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console) should be renamed to [minecraft-4j-studios](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-4j-studios) or something like that. It should have some synonyms: [minecraft-ps3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-ps3), [minecraft-ps4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-ps4), [minecraft-psvita](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-psvita), [minecraft-xbox360](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox360) and [minecraft-wiiu](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-wiiu).
- [minecraft-xboxone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xboxone), [minecraft-switch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-switch) and [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition) should become synonyms of [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition)
- Something has to be done about the Windows 10 UWP version. While [minecraft-windows-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-windows-10) could be a synonym of [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition), it would be extremely confusing, especially to new users, as not everyone knows about the other UWP version of the game or how it's different from the *almost always preferrable (citation needed)* Java Edition, and Windows 10 is installed/"force-upgraded-to" on most PCs nowadays. On the other hand, almost no one knows what Universal Windows Platform is, so [minecraft-uwp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-uwp) would too not make sense. We may consider a tag that contains *"microsoft-store"* in the name, as that is the only *(legal)* place you can get the game from.

Comment: It seems to me like most of the console versions can still be unified into one tag. You're clearly more well-versed in this than I am; can you think of any reason why we shouldn't do this?

Comment: @Schism I edited and added some stuff

Comment: ++. A few thoughts: (1) should we keep minecraft-console as a synonym, or just get rid of it? (2) I think we should consider adding dashes, e.g. [tag:minecraft-xbox-one], [tag:minecraft-ps-vita], [tag:minecraft-windows-10] ? (3) Ideally [tag:minecraft-windows-10] would just be a tag for the UWP version, I think; we could have [tag:minecraft-microsoft-store] or [tag:minecraft-windows-app] as a synonym.

Comment: @Schism 1) I'd rename it as in the answer 2) yes, you are right 3) what I'm afraid of is people starting to type "minecraft" in the tags, getting "minecraft-windows-10" as a recommendation and just choosing it even if they are actually using Java Edition, "'cause this is Windows 10, isn't it?"

Comment: I think that with a good enough usage note in the excerpt for [tag:minecraft-windows-10], we might be able to bypass that; established users could also help with retagging such questions. I think more viewpoints on this would be a good thing, though.

Comment: Barring any additional discussion, I'm comfortable with accepting and getting started on this as a plan of action. Would you mind editing the checklist post I made below to match your plan?

Comment: alex2003super & @Schism - Just a heads up that we haven't forgotten about this, but given [minecraft] is our largest tag by a long shot, us mods are discussing the potential rename and what effects this might have on SEO and such. We have a plan that we're going to put forward to the community at some point, so stay tuned for that :)

Comment: @Robotnik Just curious, but has any headway been made on this? :)

Comment: @alex2003super I think the mods are working on something, so no worries; we can hold off on actioning this for the moment :)

Comment: @Schism Unfortunately all the mods (myself included) have been pretty flat out in terms of priorities (both Arqade priorities and personal) so this was put on the backburner for a little bit.

Comment: Maybe the PS4 edition part in this post should be updated?

Answer (score 3):

This plan needs updating! Let's discuss on Manchineel's post. :-)

<strike>Slightly over a week has passed with no additional discussion, so I'm assuming that the community consensus is simply to follow the plan outlined above.</strike>

Here's a checklist of what needs to be done. Items starting with ♦ require moderator assistance.

1. ☑ Create the [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) tag.
2. ☐ Write a tag wiki and excerpt for [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition).
3. ☐ ♦ Make [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition), [minecraft-windows-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-windows-10), 
   and [minecraft-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox) synonyms of [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition).
4. ☐ ♦ Create a synonym from [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) to [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft).
5. ☐ ♦ Promote [minecraft-ps3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-ps3) from a synonym to a tag proper.
6. ☐ Retag questions to [minecraft-ps3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-ps3) where appropriate, as outlined above.
7. ☐ ♦ Merge [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition) and [minecraft-windows-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-windows-10) with [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition).
8. ☐ Retag all questions from [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console) to [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition), allowing the former to be automatically deleted.

Comment: I've written a tag excerpt for [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition] that is still in the review queue, but I should finish a full tag wiki for it soon.

Comment: Please note that Xbox 360 Edition, Xbox ONE Edition, PS4 Edition, Wii U Edition and PS Vita Edition still exist, however they all are minecraft-console, which is different codebase from Bedrock: they are all console edition. Of those, **only** the XBONE and Switch (latter for which a tag does not exist) Editions are to be considered legacy, while the others are still the last versions playable on the respective platform (even if PS3, PSV, 360 and WiiU are - unofficially - "zombie" consoles)

Comment: @alex2003super - Thanks for the info. Are all those 'legacy' console versions the same codebase? It might be worth expanding that comment into an answer that lists out every pc, console and mobile version of Minecraft, and where they fit in terms of their codebase, if you're up to it. As it stands I currently have no idea, I've only ever played the OG Minecraft, and not in many years...

Comment: @Robotnik yes, legacy consoles are still getting the same updates as the PS4, and are the same codebase, albeit with some differences in configuration and some extra features (e.g. Wii U gamepad screen gaming, PSVita Touch Screen, PS4 touchpad, different draw distances...). One of the biggest differences is that "legacy" consoles run with a much smaller world than the current-gen ones (like PS4 and XBONE)

Comment: @Robotnik done. It's huge