# Should the usage guidance for [minecraft-pocket-edition] and [minecraft-bedrock-edition] be edited so that it is clear which one is which?

Tags: discussion, tags, minecraft

Recently I’ve seen many questions tagged with [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition) even though [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) has been released for a while now. Some users may not have updated to 1.0, but I think many users don’t really know that and still consider it to be MCPE.

Should the usage guidance for these tags be edited so that it is clear which version is which or should they be merged?

I’ve seen [this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12856/minecraft-bedrock-edition) so I know that making [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition) and [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) has been discussed, but it hasn’t happened yet.

Comment: We've cleaned up the Minecraft tags to match the current state of Minecraft versioning, such that there is no longer a distinction between Pocket and Bedrock editions